# How to add an array to an array in javascript/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im currently using node.js for a project, if you can, please help. Busy making a to-do list, and want to add listname to numlists, will this work?

rl.question("What would you like to do?", function(firstAnswer){

```
if(firstAnswer == '1'){

    var addList = [];
    var numLists = [];
    for( i = 0; i< numlists.length; i++){

        rl.question("What is the list's name?", function(listName){
            numLists[i] = listName;
            rl.question("Do you want to add another list?", function
        }



    }

}
    else if(firstAnswer == '2'){




    }
        else if(firstAnswer == '3'){




        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another and easy way to concatenate arrays in JavaScript:

```
var hege = ["Cecilie", "Lone"];
var stale = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
var children = [...hege, ...stale];
```

Output will be: [ 'Cecilie', 'Lone', 'Emil', 'Tobias', 'Linus' ]

And the advantage of this method that you can add extra items between the two arrays like this:

```
var hege = ["Cecilie", "Lone"];
var stale = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
var children = [...hege, 'jon', ...stale, 'jeff'];
```

And the output will be: [ 'Cecilie', 'Lone', 'jon', 'Emil', 'Tobias', 'Linus', 'jeff' ]

Answer (score 1):

From what i understood, below is the answer if you want to combine array.

```
var hege = ["Cecilie", "Lone"];
var stale = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
var children = hege.concat(stale);
```

Children Output : ["Cecilie","Lone","Emil","Tobias","Linus"]